# Split String With Position ID

Tags: string, split, sql-server-2012-express

I am currently doing some research on data mining and my research data table are looks following

```
ID   Author  
1    Ali,Ahmad,David,Kumar
2    Aslam,Abid,John
```

Now i want to split comma separated name of authors into multiple rows with the position_ID
For Example

```
ID         Author         Position_ID  
1          Ali                 1
1          Ahmad               2
1          David               3
1          Kumar               4
2          Aslam               1
2          Shahzad             2
2          John                3
```

I have currently made a split function and the following query that can only splits the author column values into multiple row but cannot get the author position_ID in the string into a separate column. Please give me some advice.![enter image description here][1]
Thanks in advance

```
CREATE Function [dbo].[SplitString]
(@List Varchar(Max), @Delimiter Char(1))
Returns @Items 
Table (Item Varchar(max))
As
Begin
Declare @Item Varchar(max), @Pos TinyInt
While Len(@List) > 0 
Begin
Set @Pos = CharIndex(@Delimiter, @List)
If @Pos = 0 Set @Pos = Len(@List) + 1 
Set @Item = Left(@List, @Pos - 1)
Insert @Items 
Select Ltrim(Rtrim(@Item))
Set @List = SubString(@List, @Pos + Len(@Delimiter), Len(@List))
End
Return
End

declare @TAB table (strg varchar(max),Research_ID bigint)
insert @TAB
select authors,Research_ID from Citation
Select S.item As [Authors],Research_ID
From @TAB T
Cross apply [dbo].[SplitString](T.strg,',') S;
```

Comment: Please visit the following link to view the answer of the above Question                            http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/678366ed-3d48-4778-bc9a-4bf50b394032/split-string-into-multiple-rows-with-position-id#12c85a19-6b5f-4437-8b54-65aecd6a0488

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

> CREATE   function [dbo].[listtorow2](@l varchar(200),@id int)
>       returns @csv table(strdata varchar(20),id INT,Position_ID int)
>       as
>       begin
>
> ```
>   declare @xml xml
>   set @xml = '<root><record>' + replace(@l,',','</record><record>') +
>  '</record></root>'
>
>   insert into @csv(strdata,id,Position_ID)
>
> select *,@id,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) from(
> select  t.value('.','varchar(150)') as [items]
> from @xml.nodes('//root/record') as a(t)) data
>
>   return
> end
>
> go
>
> DECLARE @t TABLE(id INT,autor VARCHAR(50))
> INSERT INTO @t(id,autor)values (1,'Ali,Ahmad,David,Kumar'),(2,'Aslam,Abid,John')
>
>
> SELECT t.id,strdata,Position_ID
> FROM @t t 
> CROSS APPLY[dbo].[listtorow2](t.autor,id) t1
> ```